# Why does this query need order by to work?

Tags: sql, group-by

Why the wrong query is wrong?

```sql
-- Correct
SELECT first_name, count(*)
FROM customer
GROUP BY first_name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
 
-- Wrong
SELECT first_name, last_name, count(*)
FROM customer
GROUP BY first_name
```

source:
https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/

Comment: It has nothing to do with order by, in second you are missing to include last_name in group by. All non aggregate should be specified in group by (there are some backends that work even without it, but it is open to discussion if that is correct).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Makes sense. 1. `from customers` means look at rows from customer table. 2. `group by first_name` means throw out all columns except `first_name` column and then group identical values together. Now the `last_name` column is gone. 3. we can't select `last name` because the `last name` column is thrown out in step 2.

Comment: Oh wait. aggregate can still work on columns that are not in the group by clause.

Comment: "group by first_name means throw out all columns except first_name column and then group identical values together"   No, it does not "throw out" any columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand your explanation in comments, thus explaining here:

In first query, you are selecting columns First_Name and aggregating them into virtual buckets (group by First_Name). Second column is an aggregation function counting how many of them in given bucket. So for example:

```
First_Name, Last_Name
John, Doe
John, Carpenter
Frank, Sinatra
Frank, Doe
Frank, Short
```

You do a grouping by First_Name (and select it in the select list), you would have rows only:

```
First_Name
John
Frank
```

Adding an aggregate function (count in your case), it turns out (* in count means count rows with no particular column):

```
First_Name, Count(*)
John, 2
Frank, 3
```

Now if you consider second query:

```
-- Wrong
SELECT first_name, last_name, count(*)
FROM customer
GROUP BY first_name
```

For the result set:

```
First_Name, Last_Name, Count(*)
John, ????, 2
Frank, ????, 3
```

There isn't something that tells where the content for Last_Name come from (thus it would be a bug to include it).

If you wrote it as:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, count(*)
FROM customer
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

It would be ok. Now your problem would be getting more than you need:

```
First_Name, Last_Name, Count(*)
John, Doe, 1
John, Carpenter, 1
Frank, Sinatra, 1
Frank, Doe, 1
Frank, Short, 1
```

That would at least reveal those having duplicated and could be useful in cases.

Comment: This also makes sense to me. I was trying to follow the 'logical' ordering of the sql clauses in the blog post. The post says group by happens before aggregates. And group by some columns means only aggregates can operate on the remaining columns.

Comment: @DuhHuh, correct. To keep it simple, in select list, if a column is not an aggregate then it should exist in group by (a column in group by doesn't need to exist in select list - this is not often but useful sometimes, to make it clear you could remove just select count(*) ... in first query and then you would still get 2 rows, just count column with row values  2,3).

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

Given:

```sql
-- Wrong
SELECT first_name, last_name, count(*)
FROM customer
GROUP BY first_name
```

What was the error responded by SQL parser?

Presumably similar to:

> ERROR: column "customer.last_name" **must appear in the GROUP BY** clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 20

(Run the SQL and see this error output from PostgreSQL in [SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f2f45/1))

So just make sure all columns from your SELECT list, that are not aggregate-functions like `count` or `sum` are present in the GROUP BY list, they form the groups for which is aggregated.

#### Working GROUP BY

```sql
-- Correct
SELECT first_name, last_name, count(*)
FROM customer
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

See it working in [SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fee444/3) resulting in counting duplicates for the names.